# PHPExcel and TCPDF ERROR

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf

I am trying to generate PDF from Excel, but I get the following error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image:./var/www/projects/.../0401b0ca555959f391752bb1b0ea9ba1.jpg
```

Looking though Excel, I can find `/var/www/projects/.../0401b0ca555959f391752bb1b0ea9ba1.jpg`, but without the `.` before it.
Can the dot be a reason that failed converting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./var/www/projects/.../0401b0ca555959f391752bb1b0ea9ba1.jpg
```

The '.' before that means that it will be looking in current directory for a folder called var.

You will need to remove this . in order to begin at the root. Which is correct.

This is how it should look `'/var/www/projects/.../0401b0ca555959f391752bb1b0ea9ba1.jpg'`

It looks like you are trying to use cURL to get the image, so i suggest you should try and change the image to be a URL such as `http://URL of project folder/../0401b0ca555959f391752bb1b0ea9ba1.jpg`

Other than that suggestion its hard to know what is happeneing but i suspect the TCPDF is not playing nicely.

Comment: But, there is no '.' in excel, why it appear when i converting?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the best suggestion i can offer.